# Android Progressbar indeterminate

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I work on an app which should show a Progressbar during a few seconds (time requested to launch functions) and should disappear after the functions.

Here is my code :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val cercleProgression: ProgressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.cercleProgressbar)

        cercleProgression.isIndeterminate = true

        function1()
        function2()
        function3()


        
        cercleProgression.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    }
```

With this code the Progressbar is never visible... Do you know why ? What am I doing wrong ? (without last line `cercleProgression.visibility = View.INVISIBLE` it works but Progressbar never disappear...)

Comment: Does it visible in layout? Any other views on front of it?

Comment: @Zain yes it is visible in Layout. As said before, if I delete last line it is visible (but never end)

Comment: If the three functions are time consuming functions, then you won't see the `progressBar` You should hide it whenever these functions are up

Answer (score 0):

please give us the XML code for progress bar or you can try to add this line in your progressBar tag in XML :

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
```

Comment: `<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/cercleProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        android:indeterminateTint="@color/purple_500"
        />`

Comment: are your functions have a timer? can you try to comment on the line that makes the progress bar invisible and try it if it appears then you should put the invisible code inside the onSucess function inside the last function method

Comment: can you provide the whole code of XML that contains the progress bar?

Comment: So, put the progress bar XML code in the last line on constraint layout, because I think there is something above the progress bar that makes it unvisible and let me know the result.

Comment: is the progress bar appear in the design? if yes, just add timer before and inside timer, you should make it inVisible

Comment: I mean if it appears in XML preview window

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why, but with this code it works, but Progressbar don't end after the functions but after delay (I add a Timer)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val cercleProgression: ProgressBar = findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.cercleProgressbar)

        cercleProgression.isIndeterminate = true

        infosTelephone()
        recupererContacts()
        recupererSMS()
        Timer().schedule(5000) {
            cercleProgression.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good approach.. You should put the consuming methods in a background thread, and update the progressBar when the threads are finished

Comment: Interesting (I'm a beginner...) will try this way !